# Calculating p-value from beta and se_beta

Tags: p-value, z-test

I have a set of beta and se_beta values that I would like to calculate p-values for. I know this should be possible via a z-test, but I don't understand how it works and how to implement it. Any help would be great, either via a z-test or another method!

As a few examples:

```
site     beta        se_beta
site 1   -0.23320    3.461
site 2   0.064700    0.9543
site 3   .889300     0.0684
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Dividing $\beta$ by $\sigma$ gives you the t-value (or z). You would have to check where this is placed in your reference distribution, i.e. find out what part of the distribution lies beyond this value.

For example, if you want to test the null of $\beta_1=0$ using a t-test in Stata you'd compute:

```
reg y x1 x2 x3
di 2 * ttail(e(df_r), abs(_b[x1]/(_se[x1])))
```

for other software packages it works in an analoguous way.